# How can I use an integer I sent from another controller in JavaFX without getting a NumberFormatException?

Tags: java, javafx, model-view-controller, controller, initialization

I'm using the following code to send a `Product` to another controller:

```
    @FXML
    void onActionModifytProduct(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Product productSelected = productsTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/view/ModifyProductMenu.fxml"));
        loader.load();
        
        ModifyProductMenuController MPController = loader.getController();
        MPController.sendProduct(productSelected);
        
        stage = (Stage) ((Button) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        Parent scene = loader.getRoot();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(scene));
        stage.show();
    }
```

and then this is how I receive that code in the other controller:

```
    public void sendProduct(Product product) {
        idLbl.setText(String.valueOf(product.getId()));
        modifyProductNameTxt.setText(product.getName());
        modifyProductInvTxt.setText(String.valueOf(product.getStock()));
        modifyProductPriceTxt.setText(String.valueOf(product.getPrice()));
        modifyProductMinTxt.setText(String.valueOf(product.getMin()));
        modifyProductMaxTxt.setText(String.valueOf(product.getMax()));
    }
```

Now I need to use the integer that is sent to `Label idLbl` during the Initialization but everytime I try  and use it by putting something like  `int id = Integer.parseInt(idLbl.getText());` under `public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {` I get a `java.lang.NumberFormatException` even though I know I'm actually passing an integer because I use it at another part of the same controller (just not during the initalization). Is there any way I can get my program to read this integer during the initialization? I've been at this for awhile so any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: The `initialize()` method is called during the call to `loader.load()`, i.e. before you call `sendProduct(...)` and set the text of `idLbl`. So the text is empty during the invocation of `initialize()`, and you get a `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Why don't you just do `int id = product.getId();` in `sendProduct(...)`, and do whatever you need to do with the `id` there?

Comment: @Jame_D That definitely makes sense. I need to use it during the initialization because I need that ID to look up a `Part`  so I can load it into a TableView when it is brought up. Is there anyway I can send the integer so that it is available for use during initialization?

Comment: Huh? You call `sendProduct(...)` *immediately* after `initialize()` is called anyway. So what is the difference if you do what you need to do in `sendProduct(...)`? It's really unclear what you're asking here.

Comment: Thank you so much I finally get it now. I was so set on trying to do everything under initialize that I completely ignored that I could bring it up during `sendProduct(...)`. You just made a massive headache go away for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well **initialize()** method **is like your constructor in your class so it will get called first**.You are calling sendProduct() after it so setting the value to idLbl happens after it .So **during the invocation of initialize method still your value is empty** that's why it throws you an NumberFormatExcpetion.

Comment: That definitely makes sense I appreciate that answer. Is there anyway to send an integer so that it could be used during initialization or do I have to figure out another way to look up the 'Part' when the screen is first brought up?